cypress commands running issue
running a simple command using vs code terminal for cypress automation 1 time its showing actual results while executing with npx cypress open command and using npx cypress run showing different results from the previous test result.
here is my test suit
describe('My FIrst Test', () =\>
{
it('verify title-Positive', () =\> {
cy.visit("https://ubitelehealth.com/")// steps
cy.title().should('eq','Discreet Care for Sexual Health & Hair Loss - UBI Telehealth')
})

        it('verify title-Negative', () => {
            cy.visit("https://ubitelehealth.com/")// steps 
            cy.title().should('eq','strokealert91123')
              })
    })

here is error .
(Results)
Tests:        2                                                                                Passing:      0                                                                                 Failing:      2                                                                                Pending:      0                                                                                Skipped:      0                                                                                 Screenshots:  2                                                                                Video:        false                                                                             Duration:     30 seconds                                                                        Spec Ran:     1sttest.cy.js
while the same suit runing with npx cypress open gives different results
i run a test suit using 2 different commands
npx cypress open  it is passing one result and failing other one.
while npx cypress run fails both of the tests or scripts

npx cypress run Uses a headless Electron browser by default, while npx cypress open uses a full browser (like Chrome, Firefox, etc.) with a graphical interface.So I guess issue is with Differences in Browser Context
Ensure you are running the tests in the same browser for both commands,like this npx cypress run --browser chrome
And for the side note try to run using npx cypress open for better debugging, unless you are using any CI/CD tool.
